# Implicit resolution failure on import of implicit value with same name as method in class

Tags: scala, implicit

The following implicit value resolution issue sneaked up on me today as demonstrated in this REPL snippet:

```
scala> case class X(s:String,implicit val a:Int)
defined class X

scala> class C(i:X) {
  def a:Int = 1
  def b:Int = {
    import i.a
    implicitly[Int]
  } 
}
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: Int
           implicitly[Int]
                                                                     ^

scala> class C(i:X) { 
  def a:Int = 1
  def b:Int = {
    import i.{a=>c}
    implicitly[Int]
  }
}
defined class C
```

Although the imported implicit value `a` shadows the method of the same name, there should be no reason why the implicit resolution fails.
Can anybody shed some light on why the `import i.{a=>c}` rename is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's a bug, although I couldn't quickly identify an existing bug report.  It works without the rename in dotty.

Comment: Great idea trying it with Dotty, thanks! Glad to hear that this is working as expected with Dotty.